# How do you translate a density from Cholesky factor to density of the matrix?

Tags: density-function, linear-algebra, wishart-distribution, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose $L$ is a random $p\times p$ lower triangular matrix, with known density, $f(L)$. To compute the density of $C=L L^{\top}$, one needs to use the change of density formula. This is a little bit hairy because $C$ and $L$ are matrices.

Digging around on the web, I found the formula
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(C\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(L\right)} = 
S_p \left[ \left(I_p \otimes L\right) T_{p,p} + L\otimes I_p \right] S_p^{\top},
$$
where $S_p$ is the 'elimination matrix' which takes $\operatorname{vec}$ to $\operatorname{vech}$, and $T_{p,p}$ is the 'transpose matrix': $T_{m,n}\operatorname{vec}\left(X\right) = \operatorname{vec}\left(X^{\top}\right),$ for $m\times n$ matrix $X$.

Computing the determinant of this ugly product is beyond my capabilities at the moment. I assume this is a problem with a known solution, however.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is a $p\times p$ lower triangular matrix and $C=LL^T$, then the Jacobian is given in Equation (55) of [Henderson and Searle (1978)](https://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/32744/1/BU-643-M.pdf) (see page 16) as
$$J(C\rightarrow L) = 2^p \prod_{i=1}^p {l\,}_{i,i}^{p-i+1}.$$
They note that this result was given as Theorem 4 of Deemer and Olkin (1951).

This result is also shown in other places, such as Theorem 4.2 of [Njoroge (1988)](http://digitool.library.mcgill.ca/webclient/StreamGate?folder_id=0&dvs=1416040621625~382), who explicitly stipulates that $C$ be positive definite symmetric and that $L$ have positive diagonal elements.

***References***

W.L. Deemer and I. Olkin (1951) The Jacobians of certain matrix transformations useful in multivariate analysis.  Based on lectures of P.L. Hsu at the University of North Carolina, 1947, *Biometrika* **38**:345--367.

H.V. Henderson and S.R. Searle (1978) Vec and vech operators for matrices, with some uses in Jacobians and multivariate statistics. Technical Report BU-643-M.  Biometrics Unit, Cornell University.

The [published version](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3315017) of the technical report seems to be:

H.V. Henderson and S.R. Searle (1979) Vec and vech operators for matrices, with some uses in Jacobians and multivariate statistics.  *The Canadian Journal of Statistics* **7**(1):65--81.

M.N. Njoroge (1988) *On Jacobians connected with matrix variate random variables.* Thesis.